# Pass down state from parent component to child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which has a click event such as:

```
<div (click)="stateStatus=!stateStatus>Click me</div>
```

This click event will do something on the parent page, but I also need that state in a child component of this parent. So how can I pass down a click event like this to my child component ?

My parent .ts file looks similar to this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  stateStatus : Boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an `Input` property in your child component, like -

```
@Input() state: boolean = false;
```

and then in your parent template, pass the state value to your child component, like -

```
<child-component state="stateStatus"><child-component>
```